# A way to emulate named arguments in C

Tags: python, c

Is there a way to use named arguments in C function?

Something like function with prototype `void foo(int a, int b, int c);`

and I want to call it with `foo(a=2, c=3, b=1);` [replaced the order of `b & c` and used their names to distinguish]

*Motivation: I want a more Pythonic C, where I can easily manipulate my function arguments without mixing them by mistake*

Comment: Why do you want it, at all? If you have the values, why do you need to change the order?

Comment: Simple. I have a function with arguments that can be mixed easily and I want to help the user to not get confused

Comment: Not very sure that'd help, either, users does not need to see the function call and C devs are pretty OK with the fixed sequence. I don't believe changing anything would be useful.

Comment: Do you have another suggestion? I thought of creating a new type for each argument which should raise a warning if confused...

Comment: How can you successfully call a function without knowing what parameters it expects? You can't. Hence this functionality is useless, in any programming language. At the point where the programmer no longer know what they are doing, all bets are off.

Comment: @Lundin I don't see your point. My function expects start_day & end_day. It's quite easy to confuse which argument comes before, hence I want a named argument to "lock" the parameter to it's appropriate value

Comment: @CIsForCookies No it isn't. Have the function declaration in front of your face when you write the code that is calling it. In addition, most IDE:s nowadays have code completion, meaning you also get the information rubbed in your face when you start to type the function call. If that's still too hard for the programmer somehow, then maybe they should consider a different career.

Comment: Well you could define the function as `int myfunc(int argc, char **argv) { ... }` and use getopt() to do the parsing. But I am afraid that wont make you any friends ...

Comment: Users are not supposed to see or use the function in code. Secondly, if you don't want to be confused as a programmer, then as lundin said, keep function prototypes near you or use an IDE such as visual studio that displays the prototype upon calling a function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kinda, sorta, with a compound literal and designated initializers:

```
typedef struct foo_args {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
} foo_args;

// Later

foo(&(foo_args) {
  .a = 2,
  .c = 3,
  .b = 1
});
```

But I honestly wouldn't bother. It requires you to bend the function definition to accept a pointer, and makes calling it cumbersome.

Comment: That's the solution I was looking for, but hoped to find a simpler one

Comment: @CIsForCookies - I painted it awful for a reason ;)

Comment: In my opinion it is one of the strengths C has over python, that you cannot change the order or type of function parameters. By this, the compiler can handle many mistakes that would be semantic errors in python.
Don't try to emulate python in C and rethink your architecture instead.

Comment: I was about to suggest doing the same thing outside the function parens, but this is even closer to what OP asked.

Comment: @wolff umm... no. In Python you don't have to remember the argument order - in C you *must*.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala well, it probably depends on personal preference and routines.

Comment: @wolff. Agreed, but to play devil's advocate here, having explicitly named arguments is a way of avoiding the semantic errors that come from having multiple positional arguments of the same type.

Comment: I.e. is the call `foo(42, 5, bar)` correct - no, because `bar` would have to be passed in argument `bar` which is 2nd. And the 3rd argument is `quux`.

Comment: @wolff you can see this as a strength. I, for one, thinks it makes the usage not fun. I'm trying to write my C more Pythonic, but as StoryTeller said, this solution wouldn't do it

Comment: But well, you *could* use a macro for `foo(...)` :D

Comment: @MadPhysicist - To be fair, multiple positional arguments of the same type is a bit of a code smell. Especially if there are so many the caller has problem keeping track. I probably *would* recommend aggregating the arguments into a structure to avoid that.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - You said it, mate, it wasn't me :P

Comment: "*I'm trying to write my C more Pythonic,*" - then you are using the wrong language.   The way that Python supports this is by using a hash table (dictionary) which you would have to implement in C.  Take a look in the CPython source code at `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords` in `getargs.c` and follow the chain of function calls.

Comment: Instead of looking up the order of parameters I need to lookup the exact name. What is the benefit for this?

Comment: The point here is that if you don't really remember what the function is doing, the solution is to go read what it does, not "call it anyway". Click "goto function declaration" in your favourite flavour of IDE, 1 second of work. No need to adapt the programming language.

Answer (score 4):

Named arguments are not supported in C.

All arguments must be passed in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

C does not support keyword/named arguments. If you try foo(a=2, c=3, b=1); C compiler will flag "identifier 'a' is undefined". It is a syntax error.
It expects tokens a, b, c [declared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table) beforehand

```
int a = 2; int b = 1; int c = 3; // order doesn't matter here.
foo(a, b, c);
```

or pass by value directly

```
foo(2, 1, 3) // positional arguments.
```

My guess is that C compiler is not as sophisticated as Python's interpreter.
Python is a dynamically typed language and able to push the keyword arguments onto stack.
You can pick more descriptive names for the parameters without referring to an IDE:

```
int volume(height, width, depth)
{ return height * width * depth; }
```

Personally, I see this Python feature confusing. For instance:

```
>>> def foo(a, b, c):   pass
...
>>> foo(c=3, b=1, a=2)
>>> foo(a=2, c=3, 1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    foo(a=2, c=3, 1)
                   ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
>>> foo(2, c=3, b=1)
>>> foo(2, 3, 1)
>>> foo(2, c=3, a=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() got multiple values for argument 'a'
>>>
There are certain rules you have to observe when mixing keyword with positional arguments.
```